# list of duplicates: Subversion repository organization questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

There are a lot of questions on SO about Subversion repository organization. Perhaps some experts on the subject could go through these and identify some good candidates for the "canonical questions" that cover most cases, and close the questions that are duplicates? I'd vote to close a few but there's enough hair-splitting differences that I don't feel comfortable doing so.

Here are some of those questions:

- [subversion tags and branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633/subversion-tags-and-branches)
- [What is the reasoning behind the recommended layout for Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108682/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-recommended-layout-for-subversion-repositories)
- [Should I store all projects in one repository or multiple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130447/should-i-store-all-projects-in-one-repository-or-mulitiple)
- [Subversion - is trunk really the best place for the main development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153812/subversion-is-trunk-really-the-best-place-for-the-main-development)
- [How do you organize your version control repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222827/how-do-you-organize-your-version-control-repository)
- [What is a good repository layout for releases and projects in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356/what-is-a-good-repository-layout-for-releases-and-projects-in-subversion)
- [Shared components throughout all projects, is there a better alternative than svn:externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249085/shared-components-throughout-all-projects-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-svn)
- [How Granular are your SVN "projects": one big project containing several releated apps or one "project' per app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812497/how-granular-are-your-svn-projects-one-big-project-containing-several-releated)
- [Is a good idea to put all projects in the same trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799520/is-a-good-idea-to-put-all-projects-in-the-same-trunk)
- [Should you have branch, tag and trunk folders even for small projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574368/should-you-have-branch-tag-and-trunk-folders-even-for-small-projects)
- [Folder structure for many projects in one SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573695/folder-structure-for-many-projects-in-one-svn-repository)
- [Suggestions for setting up a subversion repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103650/suggestions-for-setting-up-a-subversion-repository)
- [Subversion Vendor Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027172/subversion-vendor-branches)
- [Recommend good SVN layout for my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275724/recommend-good-svn-layout-for-my-project)
- [SVN Repository Structure - Why is this better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214023/svn-repository-structure-why-is-this-better)
- [Repository Structure with Tortoise SVN Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214459/repository-structure-with-tortoise-svn-question)
- [Best practice for structure of Subversion repository working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197986/best-practice-for-structure-of-subversion-repository-working-copy)
- [How to Structure Subversion Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208016/how-to-structure-subversion-repositories)
- [How do you arrange several projects in a single SVN server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138628/how-do-you-arrange-several-projects-in-a-single-svn-server)

Comment: Adding to list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761513/multiple-svn-repositories-or-single-company-repository

Comment: It seems most or all of them belongs to PSE.