# Finding duplicates on Stack Overflow, programmatically

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

How would you go about finding duplicates questions on Stack Overflow? More generally, given access to a data-feed of the Stack Overflow material (titles, questions, answers, comments), what would be your design of a program which would find the 'most related' questions. "Most related" can be alternatively measured as 'most likely to be a duplicate' as well as 'most likely to be on the same topic'. These are co-related, but not identical.

Further, what programming language would you choose for this task? In particular, if your choice of language does **not** essentially boil down to 'because I know there are libraries to do most of this', then why that language?

Finally, do you think your solution would be fast enough to be used as a filter on Stack Overflow questions, to help reduce the amount of duplicate questions?

Comment: SO tries to do that already. When you type in your question title, it tries to find questions with similar titles. How well it works, well... that's another matter.

Comment: Hmmm.. this probably should have stayed on SO.

Comment: @jon really? it's so broad and speculative as to be NARQ from my perspective.

Comment: @Jeff: Possibly, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't belong on Meta.

Comment: I was really rather careful in how I phrased my request so that it belonged on SO rather than on meta.  I did not ask for a 'better' way to find duplicates or complain about duplicates.  I asked for a design for how to achieve this - a programming question.

Comment: If so many people are concerned about 'duplicate' questions. And so many people get involved in 'identifying' duplicate questions then why not build a mechanism to allow users to link/amalgamate question. Enough votes and the question gets amalgamated.

Comment: @Chris: good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Why not [download the data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) and give it a go yourself!

Comment: Because this is really really far from my area(s) of expertize.  Code generators I can write.  Symbolic math software, that too.  Interpreters, tick.  Data mining with an objective function?  Natch.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/.