# Why do a lot of questions from around 2008 seem to have really high upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting

I have seen this a lot but i ran into this question today:

[What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

And the answer (while good) has 83 upvotes which seemed a little over the top.  I see dozens of answers of this caliber every week that only seem to get a few upvotes.

Was there some sort of SO policy that encouraged people to upvote more during this period?  Am I just imagining that answers from this period received more votes than comparable ones now?

Comment: Go back and check the answers of this caliber you saw this week in two and a half years.

Comment: Will do.  Expect an email regarding this post 2.5 years from now.

Comment: There better be an e-mail in @Shog9's inbox right now, I've been waiting for this day a long time

Comment: This is hilarious

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not only have those post been around for a while, but early on there was not as many new questions to the site so the original questions got more views.  If you look at the view count (almost 60,000), then you realize that is a only a little more than 1 vote per 1000 views, you might ask instead why it doesn't have more votes.

Also, some of the core questions got asked early on in the life of the site.  Great questions still come around from time to time, but many have already been asked.

Comment: Good point about comparing votes per 1000 views

Answer (score 10):

It didn't have 83 votes then, it has 83 votes now. The site [started in 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/), so you're looking at one of the oldest posts -- the longer a post has been around, the more time it has to collect upvotes

Comment: Seems like most questions get relegated to the bowels of SO after a few weeks.  I know from my personal experience that when I get an upvote 1 month after I've answered a question it is a big surprise.  Has your experience been different?

Comment: Back then it was possible for some people to read ALL the questions/answers posted and vote accordingly. That's certainly not possible now.

Comment: When I have a problem, I search in my favourite search engine. When that leads me to an SO answer that helps me, I vote up the answer. I also vote up the question - thanks to that person asking, I got the answer immediately. Over time, these votes from search engine traffic can really pile up. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @KateGregory: You should probably up-vote the question even if you didn't find a helpful answer, assuming that the question is relevant and well-written. (IMHO of course)