# Is it now impossible to build a reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I recently tried to answer I few questions on Stack Overflow. By doing so, I noticed that almost every single time people post a wild draft and edit the post afterwards. It seems to be a common practice to include everything that might be helpful from other answers as well. It has the feeling that it is not about sharing knowledge and help people - it is all placing your answer on top - and ultimately about reputation. I am definitely not the only 
one [who discovered that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem?lq=1).

Moreover, I noticed that some *classic* questions like char[] or String for passwords [have been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords/) long time ago. Now a few people generate more and more reputation points from these answers.

Don't get me wrong. Whenever I have a problem I know that I can find the answer probably on Stack Overflow - or at least someone who knows the answer.

However, am I simply too late?

Comment: If you're really good and know your stuff you can go bounty hunting. The more complex questions that require more than couple of minutes to answer sometimes get a fat bounty as incentive to answer them.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history

Comment: If I were starting fresh I'd play the long tail - older unanswered questions in an area of expertise.

Comment: Related: [Does it feel lately like all questions have already been asked and answered and there is nothing more to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87743)

Answer (score 8):

In a word, no.  There are new questions asked that aren't actually duplicates all the time.  Some that get quite a lot of attention.  Some people are simply very good at answering questions.  This comes from practice.  You simply need to practice.  Over time your knowlege base will grow, helping you answer questions quicker, increase the types of questions you're qualified to answer, and improve the quality of your answers, increasing the likelihood of them being upvoted.

New users come along all the time that begin earning quite a lot of reputation quite quickly.

Comment: For example, someone with [over 6k rep in two months](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3037257/pranav-c-balan) of starting.

Comment: It's definitely possible but requires time spent on SO and effort. It helps a lot to answer questions in popular tags.