# Questions about “Why isn’t there generic variance for classes”

Tags: support, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

There are lot of questions on SO about this; some seem to be duplicates of others.  Often the question does not make it clear which version of C#/.Net it is talking about, so it is hard to put the answers into context.

The good answers are spread over many of the questions, so it is not clear which question should be chosen as the “master”

Would a SO mod with C# skills like to see if this mess can be sorted out and some of the questions merged.

---

[Why is C# 4.0's covariance/contravariance limited to parameterized interface and delegate types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405896/why-is-c-4-0s-covariance-contravariance-limited-to-parameterized-interface-and)
[Co-/contravariance support for non-generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251195/co-contravariance-support-for-non-generic-types)
[Why does C# (4.0) not allow co- and contravariance in generic class types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541467/why-does-c-4-0-not-allow-co-and-contravariance-in-generic-class-types)
[Why .NET 4 variance for generic type arguments not also for classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820171/why-net-4-variance-for-generic-type-arguments-not-also-for-classes/3820481#3820481)
[Why isn't there generic variance for classes in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-4-0)

just for starters...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Duplicates creating broken windows?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows)

Comment: @George, I don't think this is a duplidate of "Are Duplicates creating broken windows", as I am asking for a mod to sort out THIS set of quesions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not vote to close as exact duplicate?

Comment: I have done so, but I think this need more sorting out with the combining of quesions/answers