# Can we make it easier to find the questions that have been frequently linked or suggested as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I see a lot of duplicate questions asked and closed on both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow. Is there a [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) (or [Meta Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/queries)) query to list the questions that generate the most duplicates? If possible, **it would be nice to show the questions that have been frequently linked or suggested as duplicates in a highly visible location (such as the [FAQ tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=faq)) that is easy for new users to find.**

I just realized that this information is already displayed in the dialog box for closing a question as an exact duplicate. **Wouldn't it be great to make this information easier for new users to find *before* they ask a question?**

[image: Dialog box for flagging a question as an exact duplicate]

Comment: What is the purpose of showing them in a highly visible location?

Comment: If certain questions are asked *really* often, it would help to have a collection of these questions for new users to look through. If they can find the question they want to ask just by scanning this list, they won't have to post yet another dupe.

Comment: I fail to see what would the benefit of this be, considering that questions can be searched. The fact there are questions that are asked really often doesn't mean a user is necessarily going to ask one of those questions again; users could re-ask one of the other already existing questions, even if the question has no duplicates.

Comment: I'm trying to leverage the [80-20 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle#In_business) here, under the *hypothesis* that 80% of the duplicates cover the same 20% of all duplicated questions. In other words, I think that there is value in exposing the 20% (for argument's sake) of all duplicated questions that continue to generate 80% of the new duplicates.

Comment: I don't know of a query, but I keep a list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows

Comment: Yeah, that should really be automated.

Comment: If my [DupLinkCount](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103943/finding-earlier-answers-for-commonly-repeated-questions) were a column alongside *newest/faq/votes/active/unanswered*, you'd just sort by it to see the "real, question-generated FAQ". Assiduous users would more easily find originals to link to when voting to close, and probably be motivated to make sure the originals were *solid*.

Answer (score 1):

It's already pretty easy to search for questions here; people could. But they choose to post duplicate questions. (It's not always easy to come up with a concise enough description of a problem for a search query, but posting some source code almost always Just Works. I can't blame people too much.)

Anyone inclined to read through a list of "master questions" before posting probably already searches for their question first, so I don't think this would reduce duplicate questions any.

But it sounds like a good educational tool to quickly gain The Community Knowledge on 250 diverse topics, serve as as the basis for a printed and bound college textbook, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

We have a [built-in search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search), including some advanced options. That should allow you to find not just the duplicate questions that have been *closed* recently, but *all* of them, including the one that pertains to your particular issue.

Some people think that the built-in search isn't quite up to snuff yet (despite some recent improvements). If you fall into that camp, you can always use Google's site search with the following query:

```
"your search terms" site:stackoverflow.com
```

As some of the commenters have noted, it is neither very useful nor very inviting-sounding to publish a list of all the questions that have been recently closed as duplicates. We don't want to focus on those questions, we want to focus on the *master* questions: that's why the others get closed as dupes in the first place.

The [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (available, obviously, to moderators as well as all users that have attained 10k or higher reputation on the site) *do* provide a list of recently-closed questions. But that's intended for moderation purposes, not general use. I can't see a good reason to broaden access to that list.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must have phrased my question incorrectly! I don't want a list of the questions that have been recently closed as duplicates—I entirely agree, that's not very helpful—I want a list of the *master* questions that generate the most duplicates! If you'd like, feel free to edit my question to make that clear.