# Questions with ridiculous numbers of duplicates

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are duplicates creating broken windows?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows)

Some topics have an absurd number of duplicates. Is there anything the should be done when you come across that? It would be difficult to merge and close all the duplicates, and some good answers could be lost in the process.

For an example of this, do a search on whether you should store images as files on your server or in a database. You get:

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

[Storing a small number of images: blob or fs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325126/storing-a-small-number-of-images-blob-or-fs)

[To Do or Not to Do: Store Images in a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815626/to-do-or-not-to-do-store-images-in-a-database)

[User images - database vs. filesystem storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585224/user-images-database-vs-filesystem-storage)

[Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)

[Would you store binary data in database or in file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system)

[Should I store my images in the database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713243/should-i-store-my-images-in-the-database-or-folders)

[store image in database or in a system file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766048/store-image-in-database-or-in-a-system-file)

[Storing images on a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071636/storing-images-on-a-database)

[Do you think it's a good idea to save billions of images into Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212991/do-you-think-its-a-good-idea-to-save-billions-of-images-into-database)

[Saving images: files or blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347461/saving-images-files-or-blobs)

[Saving images in database mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753193/saving-images-in-database-mysql)

[Database for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660926/database-for-images)

And on and on... The questions vary some, but they are all asking basically the same thing. What should be done about this, if anything?

Comment: "What should be done about this"... close as duplicate? Nothing is lost by closing (merging might be messy). If you come across a really good answer on a dupe, urge the answerer to post it (or an expanded version) on the original (I can see how they would be discouraged from doing so if the other one has 300x more votes just because it was asked in Sept '08)

Comment: There's another duplicate as well. Oddly enough, I can't find it.