# Has Stack Overflow reached a saturation?

Tags: discussion

I am relatively new in computer science, but I am finding that that is very difficult for new programmers to survive on this website. This is because if a question is very basic, or if it appears too easy, the experienced programmers simply downvote it.

This was not the case when the website was started. For example, the people who asked questions like "Why main method should be static?" have 100k of reputation or even more. Why is this happening? Or do I have the wrong perception?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a connection between "many new questions get downvoted" and "Stack Overflow has reached saturation". It may have reached saturation, but I don't think bad questions getting downvoted is a sign of it

Comment: Would you rather that this site has 5000 of the same beginning questions?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO doesn't it?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Was waiting for someone to acknowledge it. Now we can have a conversation about not researching the problem.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO [Are duplicates creating broken windows?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52530/148672)

Comment: yes. I'm new and I'm like.. woah.

Comment: The site's definition of "good" and "bad" question has dramatically changed over the years. What may have been a "good" question that would receive many upvotes in the past may now receive downvotes instead for being "bad" or "lacking research"

Comment: It seems far too many people are anxious to down vote and close questions than there are people willing to answer questions and participate in discussions. SO is quickly becoming useless.

Answer (score 17):

> cause if the question is very basic or it appears easy to the experienced programmers , they are simply down voting them

It is expected to frame the question well, within the scope of the site, and in a way that can be answered.  This takes some practice and isn't something that everyone understands intuitively.

Many times, questions are asking for a poll, or a wide "where do I start" or opinions.  These are not things the site is well designed for, and those questions will get closed.

Questions should show some degree of initiative.  If the question can be answered by looking at the Table of Contents for a book that is being asked about, that isn't likely a good question.

> the people who asked questions like , why main method should be static has 100k of reputation or even more

Reputation comes with participation, patience, and a degree of luck/promotion.  As people participate in the site, people see them and look to see what they have done.  Over time the older questions have a longer period of visibility - reputation gain on a good question or answer has a very long tail.  Sometimes a question will get hot or some promotion will skew it.  I've gotten nearly 1000 rep on some questions (each!) that just got promoted right (and I didn't do any of the promoting).

If you look at [Why a static main method in Java and C#, rather than a constructor?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156336/why-a-static-main-method-in-java-and-c-rather-than-a-constructor) (note, just mentioning this here will likely add a few votes to it), you will find:

- A unique question
- A question that did substantial research prior to asking (and documented it)
- A question that is answerable
- A superb and long answer
- Two active members of the site

These things come together to get a very high rep question and answer.  It shouldn't be surprising that the people who asked it and answered it are now both high rep users.

> i am finding that that is very difficult for new programs to survive on this website

Do your research.  Format your question at least as well as you format your code.  Ask a question that can be answered within the scope and style that is expected of the site.  The scope and style are often the biggest stumbling blocks for newcomers (be they college students or CIOs - we've had trouble with them too).

Answer (score 6):

How sure are you of comparing the initial questions on SO to the questions there now in an objective manner?  Do you have the same mindset as you did when SO started?  Probably not and thus there is a great chance for there to be some bias there.  Just something to initially ponder here as I'd imagine my view of high school shifted over those 4 years that I took to get through it as in the beginning as I didn't know that much and by the end, I did know quite a bit about the system.

I'd question how do you want to use SO and how well are you seeing it used given the tons of questions coming in on most days?  While Jon Skeet could keep up with them, I'm not sure about the rest of us and this is where there is something to be said for how the community has evolved as some questions are now answered well enough that this is referenced when a question is closed sometimes.  Other times it is that someone wants to think, "Hey, I can ask this here and do like close to zero work.  Woo-hoo!" which is really want I'd imagine most of of us want to avoid as some of us enjoy programming and discussing ways to get better with it.  Course as some of us get better, this means we'd want to see different questions and others in the community may go back and help the new guys at times.

Comment: +1 I'm seeing way too many "Hey, I can ask this here and do like close to zero work. Woo-hoo!" questions.